# Unable to navigate on register screen through katalon studio mobile testing

Tags: mobile, katalon

I am doing mobile testing on katalon studio using appium. I am having an object like this android.widget.TextView - Dont have any account  Register. In this object only the Register text is clickable.

When I am running my test with this object so katalon studio is unable to identified the clickable text Register and i am unable to navigate to the register screen on my mobile through